# Read 14 bit number from 2 bytes

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, binaryfiles

I am trying to decode the run-length-encoding described in this specification [here](ftp://ftp.ecn.purdue.edu/jshan/86/help/html/appendices/Edms_VirtualBlockInfo.htm).
it says:

> There may be 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes per count. The first two bits of the first count byte contains 0,1,2,3 indicating that the count is contained in 1, 2,3, or 4 bytes. Then the rest of the byte (6 bits) represent the six most significant bytes of the count. The next byte, if present, represents decreasing significance

I have successfully read the first 2 bits for the length, but am unable to figure out how to get the value encoded in the next 14 bits.

heres how I got the length:

```
number_of_bytes = (firstbyte >> 6) + 1
```

It seams that the data is big endian. I have tried bit shifting and unpacking and repacking with different endiannesses bit I cant get the numbers I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the 6 least significant bits, use

```
firstbyte & 0b111111
```

so to get a 14 bit value

```
((firstbyte & 0b111111) << 8) + secondbyte
```

Comment: For pedagogical purpose, I would have written the all 8 bits of the binary constant `0b00111111`